# How to read multiple Verilog files in Design Compiler?

Tags: synthesis

I'm trying to read multiple Verilog files in Design Compiler, but I have found just one command, `read_verilog`. It can read only one file at a time.

If I've got 1000 Verilog files, do I have to use 1000 `read_verilog` commands?

Comment: Make a loop and iterate though a list?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev As a user of Design Compiler, the question doesn't seem unclear to me, however phrasing is not ideal.

Comment: @ahmedus OK, perhaps I was too quick to VTC. Glad that you had the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `read_file` command has more options than the `read_verilog` command and it provides a solution for your need. You can specify directories instead of single files.

The following command reads all Verilog files in the specified directories.

```
read_file {./module1/rtl ./module2/rtl} -autoread -format verilog -top MyTopModule
```

The `-autoread` option is required for the files to be compiled in the correct order. In addition, the top module of the design is specified.

If there are too many directories, the `-recursive` option saves lives.

```
read_file {./} -autoread -recursive -format verilog -top MyTopModule
```

Comment: Will this remain the same if my design has lots of packages?

Answer (score 0):

In your installation directory you should have a document named something like "dcug.pdf" (Design Compiler User's Guide).  The one I found online (dcug_2016.pdf) has an example 10-3, on page 10-14, that shows an example script of reading in multiple files.

Looks like you have to issue read_verilog (or, read_file) each time.

Comment: Would you mind let me know how to make a listofFiles ?

Comment: My answer was wrong, so I updated it.  You should also be able to type "read_verilog --help" (probably from within DC shell) and see how it works.  there should be a command line reference in the docs directory too.  Good luck.